# Relation between Signals and Events

Tags: operating-systems, os-kernel

There are POSIX signals ([linux man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)), and various event-based operating systems (such as [TinyOS](http://www.tinyos.net/), most seem to be targeted at embedded systems). But the mechanisms seem very similar.

Are the terms 'signal' and 'event' interchangeable? Or are signals a sub-set of events? Or are they two fundamentally different for some reason that I am completely missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As general concepts, the words *signal*, *notification* and *event* are mostly interchangeable, though they carry different connotations and some words wouldn't be used to denote some specific mechanisms. A particular operating system or other concurrency framework may use these terms for different mechanisms.

Some differences to watch for (with signals, events or whatever they're called) include:

- Synchronous vs asynchronous: does the sender block until the recipient receives the signal?
- Stacking: if multiple identical signals are generated before the recipient acknowledges any of them, will the recipient receive that many signals, or can they be merged?
- Associated information: is the signal just “hey, wake up”, or does it have an associated tag, or does it have a payload (which could be a pointer to a larger data structure)?
- Destinations: does the signal target a specific task (unicast), or a set of recipients (multicast), or all tasks that care (broadcast)? In the multicast case, will all the specified targets receive the signal, or is the signal cleared as soon as one task acknowledges it (this may be termed unicast rather than multicast)?

For example, POSIX signals are asynchronous, unicast (multicast if sent to a process group), they stack, and have a tag which is a small integer. I'm not familiar with TinyOS; from a quick read of the [tutorial](http://www.tinyos.net/tinyos-1.x/doc/tutorial/lesson1.html) I think they are asynchronous, unicast (perhaps with other possibilities), non-stacking, and have a payload (and, incidentally, sending an event is called *signalling* it; receiption is called *triggering*, because the *event* in TinyOS terminology is the handler instance rather than not the message).

I think the word *event* wouldn't be used if there is no associated information at all. The word *signal* wouldn't be used if there's a rich payload: with a rich payload, it's a *message*, possibly an *event* or a *notification*. GUI frameworks often call notifications of user input *events*; GUI events have a payload (e.g. to identify which key was pressed) and don't stack.

The use of the word *event* tends to promote [event-driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture) architectures, where programs are structured as event callbacks rather than as a thread that checks for notifications periodically, but it isn't limited to this use.